# laravel api url on production server

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I am using laravel 5.5 and my API URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getService/ for GET method.

what will be the URL if I put my files on the server in folder role.
I am trying this URL http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/role/api/public/api/roles/ but getting the 404 error

Comment: What have you set your document root at? It also depends on what your api routes are?

Comment: all in role folder in localhost and as well as server

Comment: Are you using this app for only api and not web?

Comment: yes only for API

Comment: but web URL is working

Answer (score 0):

Your files are only public accessible if they are in the public folder. Everything else, unless you set it chmod 777 (don't.) you won't be able to reach it.

My advice would be: write a function that returns your files and keep your files in your storage directory.

Otherwise, if you want to access the folder images in your public folder for example, you can access it by going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/

Comment: What will be the URL for API? for production server

Comment: exactly the same, except for the dns part

Comment: but I am getting 404 error when I try this http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/role/api/getService/

Comment: You just said the url you have is acessible by  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getService/ , why would you place role behind it?

Comment: this is 127.0.0.1:8000/api/getService  localhost URl (my PC) also in role folder, xx.xxx.xx.xxx/role/api/getService this is production server

Comment: So you're telling me that the same 'project' has different ways of accessing the same item, depending whether it's dev or production? The purpose of the api is developing routes to access the items you require. If you have different url's that's because you developed them to be like that and 404 mean's that the route (unless you have a findorfail) does not exist.